# Safe API and UI stopped working on Polygon zkEVM

Tags: safe-core

There is the following Safe deployed to Polygon zkEVM: https://zkevm.polygonscan.com/address/0x14cc958d41a377d46da4b939c8147bc46426e9af

I was able to to manage it through Gnosis Safe UI and interact with it using SDK without any issues.

However, today SDK stopped working and I can't access Safe through UI either. The issue is in this API endpoint: https://safe-client.safe.global/v1/chains/1101/safes/0x14cC958D41a377D46DA4b939c8147bc46426E9af

which returns:
`{"code":503,"message":"An error occurred"}`

Can somebody from Gnosis take a look?

Answer (score 0):

This API endpoint seems to work for me; here's the response I got from a simple GET request:

```
{"address":{"value":"0x14cC958D41a377D46DA4b939c8147bc46426E9af","name":null,"logoUri":null},"chainId":"1101","nonce":36,"threshold":2,"owners":[{"value":"0x8E1304EA39C47e791182BA39Fdf362A8767D7E97","name":null,"logoUri":null},{"value":"0xcC54458639704a705AD6DA32436543CCB1c3e761","name":null,"logoUri":null},{"value":"0xd2df89d7CFac69018f8e8f355407e7E5555195f5","name":null,"logoUri":null},{"value":"0x7A10033Fb8F474F28C66caB7578F4aF9e6dAd37D","name":null,"logoUri":null}],"implementation":{"value":"0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E","name":"SafeL2 1.3.0","logoUri":"https://safe-transaction-assets.safe.global/contracts/logos/0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E.png"},"implementationVersionState":"UP_TO_DATE","collectiblesTag":"1704281751","txQueuedTag":"1704281751","txHistoryTag":"1703846595","messagesTag":"1704281751","modules":null,"fallbackHandler":{"value":"0xf48f2B2d2a534e402487b3ee7C18c33Aec0Fe5e4","name":"Safe: CompatibilityFallbackHandler 1.3.0","logoUri":"https://safe-transaction-assets.safe.global/contracts/logos/0xf48f2B2d2a534e402487b3ee7C18c33Aec0Fe5e4.png"},"guard":null,"version":"1.3.0+L2"}
```

Are you still encountering this issue?

Louis